# You find a piece of paper in your bag

Tags: geometry, dissection

In your bag you find a piece of paper with a size of 5 x 5.

You want to make it a 6 x 4 but you may only make 1 continuous cut and reposition the pieces.

You are not allowed to bend or twist the paper.

[image: Piece of paper]

How will you cut the paper to make it a 6 x 4?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, and good question!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe this cut should work:

> [image: image from original post with zigzag cut]

Comment: Lightning quick. Great visual too.

Comment: Indeed it works, nice job!